# Mass Transit Filter for all Consumers/All Message Types

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to create a filter that would be executed for all message types.  Ideally, you would only have to register the filter once, instead of doing it for each consumer.  (I want to do the same thing on the publish side as well).  I would need it to be within a lifetime scope.  It's just going to pop a value out of a header, and assign it to Lifetime-scoped object that my DI container will provide (publish side does the reverse)

I watched the Chris Patterson's twitch video on Middleware, and I think it comes close to want I want around the 38 minute mark, but he registers the filter for a specific consumer. On the consumer side, I think I need a filter off of the ConsumeContext, but I just don't know how to register the filter in a way that it will be used for all consumers.  I'm using MT 7 and Autofac.  Can anyone show me some example code on how to register a scoped filter that will work for all consumers?  (and if it's very different, one that will work for all publishers)?

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to grock this now -- I thought that the generic param of a filter _had_ to be the consumer type.  I see now that I can make a Filter<ConsumeContext> (etc).  This is starting to make sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a filter that is in the lifetime scope, you need to use scoped filters (requires MassTransit v7). This will register the filter for any consumer, so that it is executed. You do need to make your filter generic, with `T` as a message type, which you can choose to use or ignore.

```
public class MyFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    SomeScopedObject _obj;

    public MyFilter(SomeScopedObject obj) 
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }
  
    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        // do your thing with _obj

        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, on your receive endpoint(s), configure the filter before the consumers.

```
e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilter<>));
```

This will configure for every consumer/message a version of your filter that executes within the container scope of the consumer.

You can do the same for publish/send.

[Documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html#scoped-filters) is on the site.

Comment: Thank you I think I understand where I'm getting confused.  I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between an endpoint, a queue, and a consumer.  It sounds like endpoint and queue are not the same thing.  Where can I go to get a better understanding of that?

Comment: A receive endpoint maps to a single queue, so they could be considered synonymous in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the docs? It has the [configuration example](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry-configuration) with retries being configured on the endpoint level and the consumer level.

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("input-queue", e =>
    {
        e.UseMessageRetry(r => 
        {
            r.Immediate(5);
            r.Handle<DataException>(x => x.Message.Contains("SQL"));
        });
        e.Consumer<MyConsumer>(c => c.UseMessageRetry(r => 
            {
                r.Interval(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
                r.Ignore<ArgumentNullException>();
                r.Ignore<DataException>(x => x.Message.Contains("SQL"));
            });
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: THank you -- Same comment that I made to Chris -- I don't quite follow the relationship between an endpoint and a queue.  If I have a bus instance that is handling many different types of consumers that consume many different types of messages, is that many queues/one endpoint?

(i'm looking for kind of a "global" filter -- one that would apply to any type of message)